# cytoscape is stuck on iniziling OSGi

Tags: java, ubuntu-20.04, cytoscape

i managed to install cytoscape 3.9.1 on ubuntu 20.04, but when i open it is permanently stuck on `inizializing OGSi container...`  window. i have java 11, path of java_home is set. everything is 64 bit...

I tried the `disable-opencl.dummy` file in CytoscapeConfiguration folder and nothing changed. looking for solutions in the helpdesk group of cytoskape i tried also to delete the CytoscapeConfiguration file,but did not worked. i tried to change the PATH to $JAVA_HOME/bin in bashrc. nothing...Cytoscape is stuck there forever. i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a recent update to both Java 11 and Java 17 that broke OSGi.  Not sure if that's your problem, but I would suggest updating to Java 17 and Cytoscape 3.10.1, which has a workaround for the problem.

Comment: i think it is my problem. it report this error when i run Cytoscape `java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid CEN header (invalid extra data field size for tag: 0xbfef at 1309602)`  and freeze on the OSGi

Comment: Thanks @ScooterMorris, i solved by updating to java 17 and installing cytoscape 3.10.1

Answer (score 0):

I am using jdk 17.0.9.9. I was facing same issue with below error "Invalid CEN header (invalid extra data field size for tag: 0x4c44 at 0)"

Solution: Added vm args as Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true and it got resolved.